# Clicking on the reputation graph not working properly

Tags: bug, reputation

Clicking on a bar for one day in the reputation chart results in the list of reputation changes for the earlier day instead. This problem occurs for all users.

Comment: Possibly related: [Reputation for graph is off by a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259692/reputation-for-graph-is-off-by-a-day)